# How to restore JSF view including the model values?

Tags: java, session, jsf, jsf-2, backing-beans

Is it possible to **restore a jsf view including the values for the backing bean**? The scenario is following:

the user is navigating within an application and the web server crashes. I want to make sure that the user has a seamless experience and can continue browsing without having to re-login.
I know that the JSF component tree can be restored with **saveView** and **restoreView** methods etc. I am saving the view state as byte array in external cache and then before **Restore phase** i am restoring the view when needed. 
So i am using one listener before **restore phase** (for restoring) and one listener after **render phase** (for saving the most current view).

restoring the view seems to work. But the **backing bean** and its fields for the current page are not restored. Is it possible to restore those fields as well? and which JSF methods would i have to use here?

thanks in advance

Comment: Easiest would be to use persistent sessions... But maybe a cluster with (session)failover is even easier (and more performant)

Comment: a cluster is the last option, we do not really want to use a cluster. Is it not possible to save the backing bean values and restore?

Comment: Backingbean values (the model) is what you control... So you could save the values to a database on each ajax request. Or put them in a 'session' that is persistent or... The 'ui-framework' should not make choices in this regard, not should java-se. Servlet contaioner or java-ee containers provide you with options to save sessions persistently. So it is up to you how to use this

Comment: Use Stateful Session Beans to make the "managed" data persistent.